# What is the difference between Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(…) and retaining the fragment--android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to save the fragments state, and after referring all over, I came across two ways of doing so,

Retaining the state of fragment using  setRetainInstance(true) in onCreate() method of fragment
and overriding Fragment's onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) method.

I tried using both and both worked for me.
I was wandering, are there any specific use cases, when to use any of them?

Comment: I think these two are the same as between `activity.onSaveInstanceState` and `activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major difference between overriding Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(…) and
retaining the fragment is how long the preserved data lasts. If it needs to last long enough to survive configuration changes, then retaining the fragment is much less work.

This is especially true when preserving an object, you do not have to worry about whether the object implements Serializable.

However, if you need the data to last longer, retaining the fragment is no help. If an activity is destroyed to reclaim memory after the user has been away for a while, then any retained fragments are destroyed just like they are not retained.

For an app with a small list of say quiz question,having users start over may be an acceptable choice. 
But if the quiz had say 100 questions, Users would rightly be irritated at returning to the app and having to start again at the first question. You need the state of the fragment to survive for the lifetime of the activity record. To make this happen, you would use onSaveInstanceState(…).

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed use case. I will select this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is how long the preserved data is retained. setRetainInstance(true) is basically useful for retaining data while a configuration change occurs (like rotation) for a very brief instant.

If the data needs to be retained while the user navigates to another app (or home screen, etc) then you should override setRetainInstance (because Android *may* reclaim your Activity's memory.)